# Clickable Slider In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to embed a slider on my Wordpress Homepage where a user can click specific image and will pop up its related info(same image for this example) on the same page. So far I use some plugins but nothing works like what I really need.Same exactly in this site

[link](http://www.embassymodels.net/#!/page_portfolio)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple plugin that will match according to your question called Soliloquy lite.If you want more options, you can purchase the premium version.